# Python error 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, dictionary, nmap

I'm new in python And I have a problem that I haven't been able to solve for a couple of days and I don't understand what the error is at all.
I am writing a program based on the Nmap program and the library of the same name, the functionality of which is to scan open ports of some list of ip addresses.
I'm trying to implement this through a dictionary, when I did everything on a static variable of ports, everything was fine, but when the program scans ports for each address, such an error is issued on the second iteration of the scan cycle.

```
'dict' object is not callable
File "C:\Users\Duoksi\Desktop\codes\python\NmapScanPy\test.py", line 47, in ScanPorts
    result = nmap.scan_command(ip, arg = attribute)
```

Below is the function code.
You can also install the library with this command: pip install python3-nmap

```
import nmap3
def Portscan():
    nmap = nmap3.Nmap()
    attribute = "-p "
    port = input("Enter ports(ex. 80,443)\n")
    attribute += str(port)
    ipport = dict()
    IPrange = ['93.187.72.82', '93.187.72.94', '93.187.72.115', '93.187.72.241', '93.187.72.19', '93.187.72.59', '93.187.72.208', 
    '93.187.72.179', '93.187.72.24', '93.187.72.137', '93.187.72.136', '93.187.72.130']
    for ip in IPrange: 
        result = nmap.scan_command(ip, arg = attribute) 
        resultclean = re.findall('\'protocol\': \'\w+\', \'portid\': \'\w+\', \'state\': \'\w+\'', str(result))
        for res in resultclean:
            ipport.setdefault(ip, []).append(res)
    return ipport
```

Output that i expect:
[pic of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYAb5.png)

Comment: The error message indicates that `scan_command` is a dictionary, not a function. Do you have a link to the documentation of `nmap3` library?

Comment: I found the documentation [here](https://nmap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but I don't see any mention of `scan_command`.

Comment: Seems to be a [method](https://github.com/nmmapper/python3-nmap/blob/master/nmap3/nmap3.py#L121). But `arg` is not a keyword argument.

Comment: I edited the library a bit so that it could do a normal scan. This method was already in it, I just finished it a little. it is located in the Nmap file 3.py

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vGoDPeCGVm7a7JY4U3lIszlb0fRXKIze/view?usp=sharing link to nmap3.py from library lines 116-130

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/md2perpe/5cca3471e3f866e77915796197d1e070) works for me.

Comment: Why do you do this: `self.scan_command = self.parser.filter_top_ports(xml_root)`? (It's from your modified `scan_command` in `nmap3.py`.)

Comment: @md2perpe idk, but it works :D because without it outputs the address 0xABCD....

Comment: i tried your code, last 4 ip's have empty brackets [] should it be like this? but it solve my problem. i think this is not very bad

Comment: Do you realize that you overwrite the method `scan_command` with the result of `self.parser.filter_top_ports(xml_root)` so it isn't a function anymore?

Comment: Um, no, I don't understand what it's about.

Comment: I don't know what it should be. The code you present in your post does it that way.

Comment: What did you want to accomplish with your modification of `scan_command`? And why didn't you tell us about it in your post?

Comment: oh, i'm sorry i just forgot about it. output without a modification of `scan_command` :<Element 'nmaprun' at 0x0000013EC9295DF0> that's why i edited that

Comment: That's an XML tree. I'm investigating how data can be extracted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unmodified `scan_command` method returns an [xml.etree.ElementTree.Element](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects) object representing an XML tree that looks like this:

```xml
<nmaprun scanner="nmap" args="/usr/bin/nmap -oX - -p 80 93.187.72.82" start="1648151628" startstr="Thu Mar 24 20:53:48 2022" version="7.80" xmloutputversion="1.04">
    <scaninfo type="connect" protocol="tcp" numservices="1" services="80" />
    <verbose level="0" />
    <debugging level="0" />
    <host starttime="1648151628" endtime="1648151629">
        <status state="up" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0" />
        <address addr="93.187.72.82" addrtype="ipv4" />
        <hostnames>
        </hostnames>
        <ports>
            <port protocol="tcp" portid="80">
                <state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0" />
                <service name="http" method="table" conf="3" />
            </port>
        </ports>
        <times srtt="64487" rttvar="50416" to="266151" />
    </host>
    <runstats>
        <finished time="1648151629" timestr="Thu Mar 24 20:53:49 2022" elapsed="1.28" summary="Nmap done at Thu Mar 24 20:53:49 2022; 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.28 seconds" exit="success" />
        <hosts up="1" down="0" total="1" />
    </runstats>
</nmaprun>
```

Here's code to get the `protocol`, `portid` and `state` from it:

```py
import nmap3

IP_RANGE = [
    '93.187.72.82',  '93.187.72.94',  '93.187.72.115', '93.187.72.241', '93.187.72.19',  '93.187.72.59',
    '93.187.72.208', '93.187.72.179', '93.187.72.24',  '93.187.72.137', '93.187.72.136', '93.187.72.130',
]

def scan_one_ip(ip: str, port: str) -> list[str]:
    result = nmap3.Nmap().scan_command(ip, arg=f"-p {port}")
    port_element = result.find("./host/ports/port")
    return [
        port_element.get("protocol"),
        port_element.get("portid"),
        port_element.find("state").get("state"),
    ]

def scan_port(port: str) -> dict[str, list[str]]:
    return {ip: scan_one_ip(ip, port) for ip in IP_RANGE}


def main():
    port = input("Enter ports (ex. 80,443)\n")
    print(scan_port(port))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

(Also available at https://gist.githubusercontent.com/md2perpe/5cca3471e3f866e77915796197d1e070/raw/cfdab2d99926030a61201748b3ec2cbbc429b7cf/main.py)

Comment: i've an error :( https://imgur.com/a/NhCtNy2

Comment: @Duoksi. What port(s) are you scanning? I'd like to know to reproduce your error.

Comment: 80 and 443(80,443).

Comment: @Duoksi. I have tried `80`, `443` and `80,443` and all work for me. Make [this change](https://imgur.com/a/4SHQ16x). What is printed?

Comment: [pic](https://imgur.com/a/fYwQF8v) program doesn't understand this funcs

Comment: @Duoksi. Sorry, I forgot a couple of imports: `import sys` and 
`from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree`. Add them in the beginning of the file.

Comment: I did imports now i have [this](https://imgur.com/a/gtOLzHH).

Comment: Change to [this](https://imgur.com/a/BA61yRE). It will create some file of the format `<ip>.xml`. Look at one of them.

Comment: [done](https://imgur.com/a/MhwqS66)

Comment: @Duoksi. Strange... No `<host>` element. I'm running `nmap` on Ubuntu under Windows (Windows Subsystem for Linux), and you `nmap` on Windows. That might make the difference.

Comment: may be, i scaned in `Nmap` ip `46.235.184.240` which always has host up, but in file o this ip there is no active hosts
Anyway thanks a lot for your help. i think i'll use the old version of [this](https://gist.github.com/md2perpe/5cca3471e3f866e77915796197d1e070) i've saved it